# 500 Internal Server Error Asp.net C# Datatables

Tags: javascript, c#

I've MVC 5 asp.net C# Project Inventory and Restaurant, when I use Datatable inside my  project here's my html:

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Resources.Tokens_Admin.Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Resources.Tokens_Admin.Category
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Resources.Tokens_Admin.Price
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Resources.Tokens_Admin.Image
                </th>
                <th>

                </th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

and JavaScripts:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dataTables-example").DataTable({
            "ajax": {`enter code here`
                "url": "/Meals/GetMealsList",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                   { "data": "Name", "name": "Name" },
                   { "data": "CatId", "name": "CatId" },                      
                   { "data": "Price", "name": "Price" },
                   { "data": "Image", "name": "Image" },
                   {
                       "data": "Id", "render": function (Id, type, full, meta) {
                           debugger
                           return '<a href="#" onclick="Edit(' + Id + ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>'
                  }

                   }
            ],
            "serverSide": "true",
            "order": [0, "asc"],
            "processing": "true",
            "language": {
                "processing": "processing...please wait"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
          public ActionResult GetMealsList()
    {
        // server-side parameters
        int start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]);
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(Request["length"]);
        string searchval = Request["search[value]"];
        string sortColumnName = Request["columns[" + Request["order[0][column]"] + "][name]"];
        string sortDirection = Request["order[0][dir]"];
        var MealList = db.Meals.ToList();
        int totalrows = MealList.Count();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchval))
        {
            MealList = MealList.Where(x => x.Price.ToString().Contains(searchval.ToLower()) || x.Category.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchval.ToLower())
            || x.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchval.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        int totalrowsafterfiltering = MealList.Count();
        // sorting
        MealList = MealList.OrderBy(sortColumnName + " " + sortDirection).ToList();

        //paging
        MealList = MealList.Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();

        return Json(new { data = MealList, draw = Request["draw"], recordsTotal = totalrows, recordsFiltered = totalrowsafterfiltering }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

when I run the view Index I've an Internal Server Error 500.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /Meals/GetMealsList
can anyone help please?

Comment: A 404 and 500 Error are two very different things and as such have different causes. Which one are you receiving? 500 denotes a server error (usually a crash of some sort) while a 404 is simply stating that the requested resource could not be found. A 404 is **not** indicative of a server crash. Try reviewing the different error codes and give some clarification to your question. If you truly are receiving a 500 error please post the error message. Otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: What is the class that GetMealsList lives in decorated with?

Answer (score 0):

First I think changing your line in Javascript:

`"url": "/Meals/GetMealsList",`

to

`"url": "@Url.Action("GetMealsList", "Meals")",`

should fix it. I'm assuming your controller is called `MealsController`?

Second, I'd recommend doing something like the following, where you create ViewModels that represent the data that datatables is passing back, that should make your life a lot easier than how you're referencing the `Request` object as it should, using model binding, map the json data to your model.

Note, you shouldn't need the `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty` lines, I just copied this code from a project where it had that already (related to a webapi).

```
    public class DataTablesSearchModel
    {
        // properties are not capital due to json mapping
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "draw")]
        public int Draw { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "start")]
        public int Start { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "length")]
        public int Length { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "columns")]
        public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "search")]
        public Search Search { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "order")]
        public List<Order> Order { get; set; }
    }

    public class Column
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
        public string Data { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "searchable")]
        public bool Searchable { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "orderable")]
        public bool Orderable { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "search")]
        public Search Search { get; set; }
    }

    public class Search
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "regex")]
        public string Regex { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "column")]
        public int Column { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dir")]
        public string Dir { get; set; }
    }
```

Then your controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
      public ActionResult GetMealsList(DataTablesSearchModel model)
{
     //Access model for the data passed by datatables.
}
```

Comment: I changed the Url inside the Ajax to "url": "@Url.Action("GetMealsList", "Meals")",
still the problem not fixed :(

Comment: @BaselMariam try what I suggested with the model as well? It might be that MVC can't find the action method because the signature it's looking for doesn't match the fact that it's posting an object. Do you get the error you've got in your html from your console or is the entire page showing that error when you've first navigated to it?

Comment: @BaselMariam what does your HttpGet method look like for this page?

Comment: entire page showing that error the error is :
"DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-example - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"